# How to use Tegra Android Development Pack (TADP) on Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, pack, tegra

I want to develop an Android application using OpenCV. I found that Tegra Android Development pack provides an easy set-up to achieve this with Eclipse but I want to use it with Android Studio. I find nothing that can helps me.

Is possible to achieve this? Is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following link will be helpfull?

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

Maybe another solution can be using Qt ?!

Comment: I want to use this pack with Android Studio not with Eclipse.On other hand Qt doesn't provide me the needed dependencies.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry - i didn't read it correct ;)  but maybe this could be a solution? http://answers.opencv.org/question/14546/how-to-work-with-opencv4android-in-android-studio/

Comment: Thanks to answer me, but this link only shows how to set-up OpenCV on Android Studio... I want to set-up the entire TADP... OpenCV is integrated in TAD